# Find the right regex for Managed Metadata Format

Tags: javascript, regex

Using Javascript, I am getting this type of raw data:

```
input = "GP0|#586fa4fb-32ad-422a-aaa2-a676df51302b\n\nL0|#0586fa4fb-32ad-422a-aaa2-a676df51302b|Consumer Goods\n\nGTSet|#cbadda79-7304-4902-b648-45b9dab70eb6"

input = "GP0|#60066230-11f1-46db-ad89-2b91ffd42ec4\n\nL0|#060066230-11f1-46db-ad89-2b91ffd42ec4|Processing\n\nGTSet|#cbadda79-7304-4902-b648-45b9dab70eb6\n\nGPP|#b6240ea6-ebbd-47ce-8516-d5208256b9d3\n\nGPP|#586fa4fb-32ad-422a-aaa2-a676df51302b"
```

I have tried the below regex but not getting the values which are Processing or Consumer Goods

```
var mmDataRegex = /#0[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]|(.*?)(GTSET|GP0|GPP|L0|$)/igm;
var match = mmDataRegex.exec(input);
```

Please help.

Comment: What do you want to match exactly ? just the values for Processing or Consumer Goods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*?` doesn't match the newline after Processing/Consumer Goods. Try

```
[^|]*?
```

inside the capture group instead.

**Edit:**

Or is this what you really want?

```
(?:GTSET|GP0|GPP|L0)\|#0[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]*\|(.*)
```

[Check it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lM7zU7/1).

Comment: I have got a new sets of data (multiple values) - how we could improve the above regex to get the description:`GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57|Argumentationshilfen;GTSet|#25b6d12b-8e8b-4233-8931-9c50587ca114;GP0|#84e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702;L0|#084e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder) `

Comment: `GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57|Argumentationshilfen;GTSet|#25b6d12b-8e8b-4233-8931-9c50587ca114;GP0|#84e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702;L0|#084e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder);GP0|#a8629bc7-a09f-4c45-a864-8506e001ef66;L0|#0a8629bc7-a09f-4c45-a864-8506e001ef66|Technische Daten" `